# Under what circumstances, a user profile information will be modified by the people other than the user himself?

Tags: discussion, support

I understand that questions and answers on programmers.stackexchange.com can be edited. My question are:

1. Is that true that user profile information too can be edited without the user knowledge/consent?
2. Who and under what circumstances that user profile information can be edited?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those people with diamonds after their names (moderators and Stack Exchange employees) can modify user profiles.

This is very rarely done (I've only done it once on a dummy account we use for spammers).

As for why it might be done there could be any number of reasons:

1. Profanity
2. Not Safe For Work images
3. Links to malware sites

are the ones that spring to mind immediately. But there could be others - it would have to be looked at on a case by case basis.

Comment: A message will also be sent if we have to edit your profile for any of the above so you know (a) why it was edited and (b) what not to do again.